# How to connect gcm server using python?

Tags: python, push-notification

I am using ubuntu 14.4 . i tried to send push notification to mobile phone.I referred following '''https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-server-to-send-push-notifications-with-gcm-to-android-devices-using-python ''' its working for my local pc .
same code I am trying in web server but i cant able to send push notification .i got error like "gcm.gcm.GCMAuthenticationException: There was an error authenticating the sender account" my webserver also ubuntu 14.4 . so please any one help me

```
gcm.py

from gcm import *
gcm= GCM("as........k")
data={"message from":"123","messageto":"1234","message":"Hi","time":"10.00AM","langid":"1"}
reg_id='AP...JBA'
gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id,data=data)
```

i added my server ip in white list but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your IP to the white-listed IP list.

The article you linked mentioned it...

> gcm: add your API KEY from the Google API project; make sure your
>   server's IP address is in the allowed IPs

When you create your access key you specify which servers can be used there, so you will need to edit the allowed server list by adding your server's IP.

- Make sure to update your Authorization key is defined in your request.
- Ensure that outbound ports 5228, 5229, and 5230 are open.
- For further errors, look at [Google's page](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error)

Comment: i added my ip address in white list but still i have same issue

Comment: Did you make sure you updated your API key that is linked to your server key?

Comment: Run through the options and see outlined on the link posted in the answer. Currently the description is a little too vague to assist fully.

Comment: am using Cloud server as my webserver. it may be any problem to access my IpAddress?

Comment: It will be your inbound firewall settings, I just set up an instance and tested now. Open 5228, 5229, and 5230 and you should be grand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68226/discussion-between-duncan-and-karnaf).

Comment: if i set white list as empty means message can be send from all the server

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I had the same problem and solved it cleaning the whitelist, saving it and re-inserting the ip of my server in the whitelist.</strike>

It seemed so but it's not true. It's just random: sometimes works, sometimes it returns the error mentioned.